# Why are my links turning yellow?

Tags: html, css

I was using Codecademy because i wanted to learn some coding. Html and CSS. Now I dont know why but i have 3 links up, all supposed to be blue, and one of them is yellow.
[image: Heres whats happening]
Heres whats happening
Also, if you can, can you tell me how to align the links in the center? 
I've tried "text-align: center;" and it wouldn't work.
Thank you.
UPDATE:
Thanks to all of you who tried to help! You guys are great people! Ive been waiting for ever for a solution to this!

Comment: Maybe that's a visited link? Also, the `text-align:center` should be applied to the containing `div`.

Comment: I highly don't recommend using w3schools to learn. It can teach you very poor practices. It's ok to use as a simple reference guide, but for learning it has led me the wrong way several times. Edit: unless you're just using the tryitnow editor feature?

Comment: To add to @RUJordan 's comment, check out http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @RUJordan, Thank you, I wont use it anymore. By the way, PhantasyRPG is a great game :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a:visited` in CSS is for styling for any `<a>` that has been visited previously. [store.steampowered.com/app/105600](http://store.steampowered.com/app/105600) has previously been visited by yourself, so the `a:visited` is being used for that link, and the [#ee9a00](http://www.colorhexa.com/ee9a00) colour is being used.

As for the text aligning, you need to set the parent to have it's text aligned to the centre. Use `div {text-align:center}` to do this.

Oh, and Terraria is a great game.

Comment: Also, set `div` to `text-align: center`, not `a`.

Comment: Oh missed that as I was too busy googling #ee9a00 to see what colour that was! But as golgothan3 said, make the parents elements text align to the center.

Comment: Thank you guys! And dotty, it seems like its just us who appreciate that game :)

Answer (score 1):

The CSS has

```
a:visited {
    color: #ee9800
}
```

This color matches the orange "Buy". My best guess is that you visited the URL http://store.steampowered.com/app/105600

Answer (score 1):

They're that color because you have:

```
a:visited {
  color: #ee9a00
}
```

The a:visited rule is applied whenever the link in question has already been visited. You've already visited it, so it gets applied. This color is an [orange-yellow](http://www.colorhexa.com/ee9a00).

To align the links in the center, use `text-align: center` on the corresponding div.

Answer (score 1):

The yellow link is due to the a:visited rule which give it the #ee9a00 color which is that yellow color.

Answer (score 1):

You have visited that link "Buy" in the past. It's specific to your browsing. Try it in an incognito/private browsing mode, and it'll be gone.

Related CSS:

```
a:visited {
    color: #ee9800;
}
```

Also, for the centering, you should apply the centering to the containing `div`:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}
```